# Catch pinch-zoom in browser

Tags: html, touch, gesture, pinchzoom

I have a web application that is basically a canvas you can draw on. I'm handling the drawing - either by mouse or by single finger touch - and it's working well.

The canvas is larger than the screen, and I need to implement my own zooming mechanism (because I only want to zoom the canvas, not the entire screen). I've added a handler to the `wheel` event, and I process Control-Wheels properly. Now I need to handle pinch-zooms.

My canvas as a `track-action: pinch-zoom` CSS settings. This enables two finger swipes for scrolling, which is excellent. I want to let the browser handle pinch-zooms, too, but I want to handle the zooming logic myself (like I do with the mouse wheel).

Is there any way to catch the pinch-zoom event and override the zooming behavior?

I'm using Chrome on Android, but this technique should also work with Safari on iOS.

Comment: I already implemented a two-fingers pinch-zoom algorithm with zoom-at-point for a canvas, but I am using `touch-action: manipulation`. If You can survive with that CSS-setting, I could post some code.

Comment: No, I can't, I can't have `pan-x` an `pan-y`

Comment: i want to do the opposite - let the browser handle the zooming behavior on individual elements.  are you implying there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nice idea btw.
i found something worth your time on [codepen](https://codepen.io/cristofersousa/pen/dMLzNY). also i stripped it down a little and inserted as snippet below. let me know if it helps you. 
additionally if you want to use library, you can try [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) or [jgestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) for pinch zooming gestures.

```js
  var image_x = 0, image_y = 0;
  var zoom = 0.5;
  var mouse_x = 0, mouse_y = 0, finger_dist = 0;
  var source_image_obj = new Image();
  source_image_obj.addEventListener('load', function () {
    reset_settings();
  }, false); // Reset (x,y,zoom) when new image loads

  function load_url() {
    source_image_obj.src = document.getElementById("theurl").value; // load the image
  }

  function update_canvas() {
    var mainCanvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
    var mainCanvasCTX = document.getElementById("mainCanvas").getContext("2d");
    var canvas_w = mainCanvas.width, canvas_h = mainCanvas.height; // make things easier to read below
    // Keep picture in bounds
    if (image_x - (canvas_w * zoom / 2) > source_image_obj.width) image_x = source_image_obj.width + (canvas_w * zoom / 2);
    if (image_y - (canvas_h * zoom / 2) > source_image_obj.height) image_y = source_image_obj.height + (canvas_h * zoom / 2);
    if (image_x + (canvas_w * zoom / 2) < 0) image_x = 0 - (canvas_w * zoom / 2);
    if (image_y + (canvas_h * zoom / 2) < 0) image_y = 0 - (canvas_h * zoom / 2);
    // Draw the scaled image onto the canvas
    mainCanvasCTX.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_w, canvas_h);
    mainCanvasCTX.drawImage(source_image_obj, image_x - (canvas_w * zoom / 2), image_y - (canvas_h * zoom / 2), canvas_w * zoom, canvas_h * zoom, 0, 0, canvas_w, canvas_h);
  }

  function reset_settings() {
    image_x = source_image_obj.width / 2;
    image_y = source_image_obj.height / 2;
    zoom = 1;
    update_canvas(); // Draw the image in its new position
  }

  document.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      zoom = zoom * 1.5;
    } else {
      zoom = zoom / 1.5;
    }
    update_canvas();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (e.buttons > 0) {
      window.getSelection().empty();
      image_x = image_x + zoom * (mouse_x - e.clientX);
      image_y = image_y + zoom * (mouse_y - e.clientY);
    }
    mouse_x = e.clientX;
    mouse_y = e.clientY; // Save for next time
    update_canvas(); // draw the image in its new position
  }, false);

  function get_distance(e) {
    var diffX = e.touches[0].clientX - e.touches[1].clientX;
    var diffY = e.touches[0].clientY - e.touches[1].clientY;
    return Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY); // Pythagorean theorem
  }

  document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length > 1) { // if multiple touches (pinch zooming)
      finger_dist = get_distance(e); // Save current finger distance
    } // Else just moving around
    mouse_x = e.touches[0].clientX; // Save finger position
    mouse_y = e.touches[0].clientY; //
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stop the window from moving
    if (e.touches.length > 1) { // If pinch-zooming
      var new_finger_dist = get_distance(e); // Get current distance between fingers
      zoom = zoom * Math.abs(finger_dist / new_finger_dist); // Zoom is proportional to change
      finger_dist = new_finger_dist; // Save current distance for next time
    } else { // Else just moving around
      image_x = image_x + (zoom * (mouse_x - e.touches[0].clientX)); // Move the image
      image_y = image_y + (zoom * (mouse_y - e.touches[0].clientY)); //
      mouse_x = e.touches[0].clientX; // Save finger position for next time
      mouse_y = e.touches[0].clientY; //
    }
    update_canvas(); // draw the new position
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener('touchend', function (e) {
    mouse_x = e.touches[0].clientX;
    mouse_y = e.touches[0].clientY; // could be down to 1 finger, back to moving image
  }, false);
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    canvas {
      background: #e74c3c;
      border: 4px solid black;
    }
    .box-photo {
      border: 1px dashed black;
    }
    .box-photo img {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<body onload="load_url();">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-photo">
      <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="500" height="600">
        <input id="theurl" value="https://mlb-s1-p.mlstatic.com/relogio-mondaine-classico-78527-original-a-prova-dagua-202101-MLB20273713546_042015-F.jpg">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```